# Show a specific route instead of error page (404) - Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Instead of an error page / 404 I want to just show the /sitemap page. Of course I don't want a redirect and I still want the 404 HTTP response header to be set.

Is this possible? All I can see is how to set templates in Twig.

I definitely don't want a redirect.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As shown in [the Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html) you can override error pages in two ways:

- Overriding the templates
- Using a custom exception controller

If you only want to show the `/sitemap` route on a 404 (`HttpNotFoundException`) exception you could override the Twig exception template by creating a new template in `app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`.

Another way that is not shown in the cookbook is using an event listener. When the kernel encounters an exception, a [`kernel.exception`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/internals.html#kernel-exception-event) event is dispatched. By default, this exception is caught by the exception listening provided by Twig. You can [create your own event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) which listens for the `kernel.exception` event and renders a page:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
{
    if ($event->getException() instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        $response = $this->templating->renderResponse(/* sitemap */);

        $event->setResponse($response)
    }
}
```

(I haven't tested this code, so you should try it yourself! And you have to inject the templating service into the event listener yourself, of course).

Comment: Thanks, the event listener is the way to go I think, but $this->templating isn't valid. I've also tried $event->templating. I don't think usual controller methods are available. I get a Undefined property: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent::$templating in...

Comment: You're correct, the usual controller methods are not available as those are aliases for method calls on services. You should inject the `templating` service into the event listener yourself in the service description.

Comment: I didn't realist at the time this just sets a Twig template, not an actually page or controller.

Comment: The 'templating' service just shows a Twig template and doesn't render a controller

Comment: Of course it doesn't render a controller. That's the job of the controller. But it should render the template...you can check [the source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php) of the `Controller` class to see what is used to render templates in the controller and inject those services into your event listener.

Comment: Of course you are dead right, and maybe there's no better method, but this answer doesn't easily satisfy the question I asked. Thanks though and it doesn't look like there'll be any better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple web app composed by several Symfony3 bundles, all of whose controllers extend a BaseController. I have a AdminBundle too. To show a given page for every not existent url, I hacked (and made simpler) the original ExceptionController.php (from the TwigBundle):

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use MyApp\Controller\BaseController;

use Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FlattenException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\DebugLoggerInterface;

class ExceptionController extends BaseController
{
    /**
     * Converts an Exception to a Response.
     *
     * @param Request              $request   The request
     * @param FlattenException     $exception A FlattenException instance
     * @param DebugLoggerInterface $logger    A DebugLoggerInterface instance
     *
     * @return Response
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException When the exception template does not exist
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, FlattenException $exception, DebugLoggerInterface $logger = null)
    {
        $currentContent = $this->getAndCleanOutputBuffering($request->headers->get('X-Php-Ob-Level', -1));
        $code = $exception->getStatusCode();
        return $this->render('MyappAdminBundle:Admin:error.html.twig',
            array(
                'status_code' => $code,
                'status_text' => isset(Response::$statusTexts[$code]) ? Response::$statusTexts[$code] : '',
                'exception' => $exception,
                'logger' => $logger,
                'currentContent' => $currentContent,
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param int $startObLevel
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getAndCleanOutputBuffering($startObLevel)
    {
        if (ob_get_level() <= $startObLevel) {
            return '';
        }

        Response::closeOutputBuffers($startObLevel + 1, true);

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

I define my error template as I liked.

I need to add the following line within config.yml

```
twig:
    exception_controller: MyappAdminBundle:Exception:show
```

ps I am sure my code can be improved, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create this file:

- Symfony 3: `/app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig`
- Symfony 4: `/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig`

... and copy this line into it:

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\HomepageController::index')) }}
```

That's it. This will show the home page with a 404 status code. It only works in `prod` environment (clear the cache!), since in `dev` and `test` Symfony always shows its exception page.

References:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-error-templates
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#testing-error-pages-during-development