# Symfony2 : Redirect user to index page when page not found or 404 errors thrown

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.4

I want to redirect user to particular page When page not found error comes in symfony2.

For customization of error page message I created

```
app\Resources\TwigBundle\views\Exception\error404.html.twing
```

But now I want to redirect user to particular page. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You will find your joy here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983082/show-a-specific-route-instead-of-error-page-404-symfony2

Answer (score 2):

You would want to create an [event listener](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) that listens for the `kernel.exception` event the kernel dispatches when it encounters an exception.

Then, you would check inside the listener if the exception is an instance of `NotFoundHttpException`, and if it is, redirect to the page of your choice.

Here's an exemple:

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/EventListener/AcmeExceptionListener.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class AcmeExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if ($event->getException() instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll need to register the event listener. It is just a service, so you just need to register it as usual.

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    kernel.listener.your_listener_name:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\AcmeExceptionListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onKernelException }
```

Comment: Thanks. Because I am new to symfony, How can I register it?

Comment: I've added an example in my answer. Don't forget that [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) can be very useful sometimes! (The examples I've included are basically the same as the documentation's examples.)

Answer (score 0):

You must use .htaccess for this. Please see [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml).

Comment: No. This is for Symfony2, not the regular 404 errors from Apache. And the OP might be not using Apache.